# Name of this 'horizontal section' diagram and how to implement in PyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, data-visualization

I need to create a plot with matplotlib/pyplot in a very specific way. I want the curve to never go up again, instead I want these horizontal sections with the little overstanding line, like shown in the picture:

[image: Text]

Source: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-precision-recall-py

My problem is I don't know how this type of line-style is even called so I don't know what to search for. It is often used for PR-Curves in deep learning.

Does anyone know how this is called and maybe also how to plot a graph in this style with pyplot?

This is my current approach by just plotting with the plot function. As you can see there are these rising edges which I want to get rid of.

```
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=3)
```

[image: My approach]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you cited from scikit-learn uses `drawstyle='steps-post'` (this [demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html) illustrates what it does), so try

```
plt.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps-post')
```